# Opening a Form from a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Why the appearance of the `f1` Form is different from what you'll see in a WinForms application? I mean in terms of margin sizes, button borders, etc.

How can I get exactly the same appearance?

Thanks.

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnContentRendered(EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();

        f1.ShowDialog();

        base.OnContentRendered(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you're using a different framework? I don't understand what you're asking here

Comment: Try calling `System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles()` in your WPF application to style it accordingly.

Comment: @WeSt: It works, thanks. Add an answer so I can mark it!

Comment: That would make [duplicated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6807302/1997232).